# Is there a way to embed an lwc (which I create in my org) into another LWC which is from Managed Package?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package

I have a Managed Package with several LWC's .
And I want to create ***another LWC*** , in which my clients will have possibility to put their LWC.
**So I need *some container in my Managed LWC where I can put Customer LWC***

Does Lightning Web Components provide us with such possibility to accomplish this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible as the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_configuration_tags) states (note on the `isExposed` attribute):

> A custom Lightning web component can’t access a Lightning web component or module in a custom namespace. It can access Lightning web components and modules only in the `c` and `lightning` namespaces.

This would be the case for using slots, as described in [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots), if it were supported by the framework. Maybe it will be supported at some point in the future...

Comment: One of the Partner Tech Talks covered ("safe harbour") an up-coming feature allowing cross-namespace LWC usage in an LWC template. Quite when that might appear is, of course, anyone's guess.

Comment: This should work with the new Lightning Web Security feature that is now in Beta and may replace Lightning Locker at some point in the future, give it a try to see if it solves your problem: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_security_intro.htm&type=5&release=234